# "Canvas: trying to draw too large bitmap" problem in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-bitmap

When I try to get `bitmap` from website, `Canvas: trying to draw too large` problem is occured.

So I search this problem on google and many people wrote their solutions, but that solution is about bitmap file in directory drawable.

- What should I do if the bitmap image taken from the website is too large?

This is my code.

```
            Thread mThread = new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        URL url = new URL(postImgUrl);

                        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                        conn.setDoInput(true);
                        conn.connect();

                        InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
                        postImgBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                        inputStream.close();
                        conn.disconnect();

                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };
            mThread.start();
            mThread.join();

            if (postImgBitmap != null){
                postImg.setImageBitmap(postImgBitmap);
```

When a problem occurs, variable postImgUrl is  "http://www.hstree.org/data/ck_tmp/202001/de3kOOtFqV6Bc2o7xCa7vg1UwFWJ.jpg" and variable postImg is ImageView.

Please advise me.

Comment: Before `setImageBitmap()`, you can get a scaled bitmap with `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means the size of Bitmap is too large for the ImageView.
Before `setImageBitmap()` to ImageView, you can scale the large Bitmap to a smaller one with `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap()`. Then you can safely set the Bitmap to ImageView.

A sample code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String imageUrl
        = "http://www.hstree.org/data/ck_tmp/202001/de3kOOtFqV6Bc2o7xCa7vg1UwFWJ.jpg";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                URL url = null;
                try {
                    url = new URL(imageUrl);
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                try (BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream
                        = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream())) {
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bufferedInputStream);

                    final Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
                        bitmap,
                        (int) (bitmap.getWidth() * 0.1),
                        (int) (bitmap.getHeight() * 0.1),
                        true
                    );

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            imageView.setImageBitmap(scaledBitmap);
                        }
                    });
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: First, thank you for your response.
However, I am new to the second try-catch syntax.
Can you explain to me?

Comment: @kimbsu00 It is a try-with-resources statement and AutoCloseable feature introduced from Java 7 (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/try-with-resources.html). You don't need close InputStream by yourself anymore.

Comment: Thank you. It really helped me a lot.

Comment: Do you happen to know how to set the size of the bitmap image to the maximum size allowed by ImageView? 
Or do you happen to know how to get maximum width and height allowed by ImageView?

Comment: @kimbsu00 I have no idea. But actually I think all you need are the width and the height of your ImageView. So maximum size you need would be `ImageView.getWidth()` or `ImageView.getHeight()`.

Comment: @kimbsu00 Also, the Android official document advices so (https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskScalePhoto).

Comment: Thank you again for your help.It really helped me a lot.

Comment: @kimbsu00 If your question is solved, please accept my answer to close the question.